# What to write as package name in TestNg.XML if using a default package for the program

Tags: java, testng

I am very new to TestNG. Today I was trying to run four test cases by using TestNG.xml.
I wrote the code as per the documentation and executed it. As soon as the execution start I got the above exception. I went through the similar question asked before and come to know that the package name which I am giving is wrong. 
Can anyone please tell me what name I should give as package name it I am using a default package.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="MyFirstSuit">
   <test name="MonsterOld" >
  <classes>
    <class name="default.MonsterUpdate" />
  </classes>
</test>

<test name="MonsterNew">
  <classes>
    <class name="default.MonsterUpdateNewProfile"/>
  </classes>
</test>

<test name="ShineOld">
  <classes>
    <class name="default.shineUpdate"/>
  </classes>
 </test>

<test name="ShineNew">
   <classes>
     <class name="default.shineUpdateNewProfile"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
```

```
 Exception which i got for this xml file-
   org.testng.TestNGException: 
   Cannot find class in classpath: default.MonsterUpdate
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:543)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:17)
at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:10)
at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:168)
at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

[image: This is the screen shot of eclipse. The !st red circle shows the package which I am using and the 2ND red circle shows the classes which I am trying to run]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got Solution For the Exception.
If you are using a default pakage then don't write any pakage name before the class name.

New working Code-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

 <suite name="MyFirstSuit">
  <test name="MonsterOld" >
    <classes>
      <class name="MonsterUpdate" />
      </classes>
 </test>

  <test name="MonsterNew">
    <classes>
      <class name="MonsterUpdateNewProfile"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="ShineOld">
 <classes>
   <class name="shineUpdate"/>
 </classes>
</test>
<test name="ShineNew">
  <classes>
   <class name="shineUpdateNewProfile"/>
  </classes>
 </test>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the classname without default.

```
<class name="shineUpdate"/>
```

However, it is good to have [packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html) to logically group related classes and I would recommend you do create a package to put your tests into.